# Protected worksheet Refresh table(not pivot)

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I need to protect my worksheet, but still be able to refresh the underlying data(table).

My worksheet is an Invoice with the body of the invoice is a table linked to underlying query.  How do I refresh this data when I have locked down (protected worksheet) w/password?  The only code I can find seems to unlock & Lock by storing the password within the VBA.   There has to be another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lock your sheet like so in the workbook open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Protect Password:="Password123", UserInterfaceOnly:= True

End Sub
```

The `UserInterfaceOnly` argument allows VBA to make changes to the worksheet but not the user - unforunately this option can only be used programatically on not via GUI

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, I was hoping not to store the actual password within the code.  Is there another way?  I also want to refresh the table only, due to the rest of the worksheet has linked or calculated fields.

Comment: `Is there another way?` - Afraid not, and even if there were it only takes 2 seconds and about 10 lines of code to break a worksheet password anyway so I wouldn't worry about it. If someone really want's to undo that password they will find a way...